# Google BigQuery: Upload ExecuteQuery result to Google Cloud Storage in json format

Tags: google-bigquery

I am importing bigquery table which contains repeated records, I need to upload those records to google cloud storage, How can i convert the result to json format so that i can store it in google cloud?

Below is my code:

```
  BigQueryClient Client = BigQueryClient.Create("test", _googleCredential)

   string query = @"select * from `projecttest.TestDataset.CostData`";

 result = Client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null, queryOptions: new QueryOptions { UseLegacySql = false });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you do this for whole table - you should rather use Export job with JSON format

Comment: Thank you for your response, Could you please provide document for using export job using c#. Are you refering to method ExportJsonToGcs in  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/2027a8ee13356fed4c045e89f38cd0e680476c37/bigquery/api/BigqueryTest/BigqueryTest.cs

Comment: I have to import wildcard tables which have repeated records in it . So it would be difficult to create json mnually by featching each row/column. Do we have any method to skip creating json manually ?

Comment: sure. you can try this method (i am not c# person anymore so cannot say for sure - related api is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) and you do not need set schema when you do export - see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract) for required attributes to be set. also - important - `SELECT *` incur cost of scanning whole table vs export is free

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Exporting Table Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) BigQuery functionality that can be implemented to export your tables data from **BigQuery** to **GCS** in several formats, such as [JSON, CSV and Avro](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types) export formats.

I suggest you to take a look on the [Exporting data stored in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) official documentation that contains some useful examples to submit an extract job via API, Web UI, Command-line and **Client Libraries** in case you use a specific programming language as shown in the following C# code sample:

```
public void ExportJsonToGcs(
    string datasetId, string tableId, string bucketName, string fileName,
    BigQueryClient client)
{
    StorageClient gcsClient = StorageClient.Create();
    string contentType = "application/json";
    // Get Table and append results into StringBuilder.
    PagedEnumerable<TableDataList, BigQueryRow> result = client.ListRows(datasetId, tableId);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var row in result)
    {
        sb.Append($"{{\"title\" : \"{row["title"]}\", \"unique_words\":\"{row["unique_words"]}\"}}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
    // Save stream to Google Cloud Storage.
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString())))
    {
        var obj = gcsClient.UploadObject(bucketName, fileName, contentType, stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this code , but i have to upload table which have record datatype in it. Is it feasibleto import those tables ?

Comment: Based on the [Specifying nested and repeated columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#specifying_nested_and_repeated_columns) documentation, you should have no problem to upload tables with `RECORD` datatypes since BigQuery supports nested and repeated data from source formats that support object-based schemas, such as JSON files.

Comment: If I need to upload n number of tables then its not a good practise to manually specify schema for each table.

Comment: I agree. The nested and repeated columns reference was mentioned to point out the support of [RECORD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) and [STRUCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct-type) datatypes. Based on this, you should be able to use the **Exporting Table Data** BigQuery feature without problem when handling these records.

Comment: However, since you cannot export data from multiple tables in a single export job, I think you could get a BigQuery table list and use it to move your tables one by one to/from GCS, adding the Schema auto-detection when loading them into BigQuery to detect the fields datatypes automatically.